# Vagrant up on Laravel/Homestead stuck on ssh auth method

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

Can anyone help me, the vagrant up stops every time at SSH auth method. I have been stuck for 4 days. Please guys help me.

Vagrant Version is 1.9.2

Virtual Box Version is 5.0.16

```
    Sam@sam-PC MINGW32 /c/www/Homestead (master)
    $ vagrant up
    Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
    ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
    ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
        homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
        homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
    ==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
        homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    ==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    ==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
    ==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
        homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
        homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
        homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
    Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
    Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
    the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

    If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
    Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
    are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

    If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
    working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
    problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
    Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
    as well.

    If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
    the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Here is my YAML File

```
    ---
    ip: "192.168.10.10"
    memory: 2048
    cpus: 1
    provider: virtualbox

    authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    keys:
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    folders:
        - map: ~/www/Sites
          to: /home/vagrant/Sites

    sites:
        - map: test.app
          to: /home/vagrant/Sites/Test

    databases:
        - homestead

    # blackfire:
    #     - id: foo
    #       token: bar
    #       client-id: foo
    #       client-token: bar

    # ports:
    #     - send: 50000
    #       to: 5000
    #     - send: 7777
    #       to: 777
    #       protocol: udp
```

Can anyone help me, the vagrant up stops every time at SSH auth method. I have been stuck for 4 days. Please guys help me.

Vagrant Version is 1.9.2

Virtual Box Version is 5.0.16